# react native get accurate position

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, positioning

Recently I work on a positioning module with react native, trying to positioning by [geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation?). But the problem is that I can not get the accurate position with GPS on.

Demo:

```
let Timer;
export default class XXX extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        timer = setInterval(this.getLocation,8000);
    }
    getLocation() {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            location => {
                let result = "longitude ：" + location.coords.longitude +
                    "\nlatitude：" + location.coords.latitude;
                alert(result);
            },
            error => {
                alert("failed to positioning："+ error);
            }
        );
    }
    onBackAndroid = () => {
        if (this.lastBackPressed && this.lastBackPressed + 2000 >= Date.now()) {
        return false;
    }
        clearInterval(timer);
        return true;
    };
}
```

Accuracy of the method ranges from 10m to 200m, not meeting requirement.
I wonder if there are any suggestions to improve the accuracy of this method? Or is there are any other methods to get a accurate position in react native?